# Devise: You have to confirm your email address before continuing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using `devise` and `simple_token_authentication` for my JSON API. Once I have an email and token, according to [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication), I should be authenticated and thus be able to access a controller action. However, when I try the following curl command:

> curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:
>   application/json"  -H "X-User-Email: donato@myemail.io" -H
>   "X-User-Token: NFHCVtZdjy2zwT_hTezU" -X GET
>   http://localhost:3001/users/11.json

I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Set-Cookie:
_my_app_session=Q0VTT1NNNGx1K2hoK3pSMXBZNFhzaG1BSXd5cGg3WWhkTmVtekEvSkc4Q2FqSkF4anZMYVc1dENWNzJkRUhwcFN2VG8yb0xzeGk4cjFtSm5tWHIxb1E9PS0tZ3V6cXZRL0ZKR3hxSVh1NWxjeENLZz09--145a421cac94ab6be992df6b0f534968ba751231; path=/; HttpOnly X-Request-Id: 8425dd4c-d13e-465b-997e-847288ddbdf0 X-Runtime: 0.027902 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"error":"You have to confirm your email address before continuing."}Mac-mini-3:my_app donato$
```

Now checked my user model out:

```
User.first.attributes.slice("confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "unconfirmed_email")
=> {"confirmation_token"=>"Lvh4XzW5wAeXmHVFEFQk", "confirmed_at"=>nil, "confirmation_sent_at"=>Fri, 10 Mar 2017 22:15:20 UTC +00:00, "unconfirmed_email"=>nil}
```

It seems like it is already confirmed?

Actually, once I did this:

```
user.confirmed_at = Time.now
user.save!
```

Then that error went away. Devise has a method `skip_confirmation!`. But when I create a user from my mobile app, devise handles everything. How could I hook into devise to invoke this method?

Comment: So do you have an update?

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable `:confirmable` with `Devise`? because this is connected to the `:confirmable` module in `User.rb`

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

The .skip_confirmation! method needs to be called before saving of the user.

```
user = User.new
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save
```

This :confirmable module adds some fields in the user model and in the users table, if you correctly fill those fields you will be able to skip the confirmation.

```
  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

You can ask me more details about the confirmable module as I configured it for my application.

Comment: Yes I know all this but the creation of the User is handled by Devise. So how should I hook into Devise in order to call skip_confirmation! ?

Comment: for that , you generate devise controllers with rails generate `devise:controllers [scope]` and there you can edit the `devise/registrations_controller#create action` so that you confirm the user before saving. Anyway you can check devise controller in your .rvm folder. It will be included in your gem files inside the devise folder

Are you sure that you do not have the :confirmable module activated somewhere? could you do a CTRL+SHIFT+F search for `confirmable`. Good night

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers